# How to pass data from Component to HOC Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, nservicebus-sagas

I want to pass the contextHOC constant to the HOC component but I got a contextHOC is not defined error message so How to pass data named contextHOC from Component named MileageExpenseFormikSteps to HOC Component withHOC

here is the HOC component

```
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import React from 'react';

    const withHOC = Component => {
    class Hoc extends React.Component
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
            const s = this.props.test;
        }

        render(){
            console.log("sss",this.props.test)
            return <Component/>
        }
        
     } 
     //console.log("sss111",this.props.test)

     return Hoc;
     
    }

    export default withHOC;
```

and here is my component which contains the value of contextHOC

```
     import withHOC from './hoc';
     const test= {};

     const MileageExpenseFormikSteps = ({userToken, setFieldValue}) => {
     const contextHOC = useFormikContext();
     console.log("contextHOC",contextHOC)

     return (
     <FormikConsumer>
      {({values}) => {
        const steps = values.expense_detail.mileage_expense_steps

        return (
          <div className={'col'}>
            <SingleCardFullPageWidth width={12}
              title={StepsCardTitle(values.expense_detail.distance, values.ht_amount, 
             steps.length)}
            >
              <Fld name={"expense_detail.return_trip"}
                label={I18n.t("views.mileage_expense.return_trip")}
                classes={"horizontal-switch medium-top-margin"}
                tooltipMessage={ steps.length > 1 ? 
                I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.mileage_expense.return_trip_not_allowed') : 
                null }
                tooltipIcon={ "fa-exclamation-circle" }
                tooltipColor={ "orange" }
              >
                <SwitchField isDisabled={steps.length > 1 ? true : false}/>
              </Fld>

              <MileageExpenseSteps
                steps={steps}
                userToken={userToken}
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                isReturnTrip={values.expense_detail.return_trip}
              />
            </SingleCardFullPageWidth>
          </div>
        )
         }}
          </FormikConsumer>
        )
       }

      export default withProps({test:contextHOC}) (withHOC(MileageExpenseFormikSteps))
```

Comment: Why can't `withHOC` access the context directly? Where is `contextHOC` undefined, the console log? Check the `useFormikContext` hook.

Comment: in the MileageExpenseFormikSteps component I made a console.log to the contextHOC and I saw the result properly but when I pass contextHOC in withHOC the execution returns me that contextHOC is not defined

Comment: Where do you define a `contextHOC` to be passed to `withProps` in `withProps({test:contextHOC})(withHOC(MileageExpenseFormikSteps))`? It appears to be undefined in your snippet.